# Como eu atualizo o valor de uma variável dentro de outro script?

Tags: python-3.x

Basicamente para ilustrar melhor, supõe-se que eu tenho um arquivo.py que tenha o seguinte conteúdo:

```
token = ''
```

Eu criei o atualizar_arquivo.py que tem a meta de atualizar a variável token para outro valor em que necessariamente tenha que ser um input.
A minha pergunta é como ficaria o arquivo atualizar_arquivo.py.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria:

```
import arquivo

new_token = input("Entre com seu token: ")

arquivo.token = new_token

print(arquivo.token)
```

Mas isso só funciona em tempo de execução.
Quando o programa finalizar o token retorna para o valor padrão que no caso é vazio